# randomForest **sometimes** predict()s NA on a training dataset

Tags: r, random-forest

I got strange behaviour from randomForest: I sometimes get NAs predicted on my training dataset!! It's totally random, see the two runs getting different results!

```
> rf <- randomForest(formula(rfFormula), data = df2, ntree = 20, keep.forest = TRUE) 
> pr <- predict(rf, type = "response")
> any(is.na(pr))
[1] TRUE
> which(is.na(pr))
1283 
1001 
> 
> rf <- randomForest(formula(rfFormula), data = df2, ntree = 20, keep.forest = TRUE) 
> pr <- predict(rf, type = "response")
> any(is.na(pr))
[1] FALSE
> which(is.na(pr))
named integer(0)
```

There are no NAs in my dataset:

```
> any(is.na(df2))
[1] FALSE
```

**So why is that? Is it a bug in `randomForest`? Or some trouble related to OOB predictions?**

1) Note that I use 119 variables in the formula.

2) Note that I use `predict(rf, type = "response")` instead of `predict(rf, df2, type = "response")`, [that would be a mistake](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112052). I need to use the first way to get the OOB predictions :-)

Comment: First: Can you try your code with this `rf <- randomForest(formula(rfFormula), data = df2, ntree = 20, keep.forest = TRUE, na.action=na.omit)`. This is to make sure you do indeed run without `NA`. Second: Do you have any categorical variable that has more than 53 categories?

Comment: @joran yeah, that's it!!! Thanks! The irony is that I actually put `ntree = 20` for debugging purposes, to be able to quickly debug all errors in my script, and it actually generated a  tough one :-D Setting ntree = 100 fixed it. :) Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was exactly for the reason mentioned by @joran. The low number of trees (20) allowed that sometimes it did happen by chance that one observation was used to construct all 20 trees, and thus there were no trees to get the OOB (out-of-bag) prediction on that observation.

Setting `ntree = 100` fixed it.

PS: The irony is that I actually put `ntree = 20` for debugging purposes, to be able to quickly debug all errors in my script, and it actually generated a new, very tough one, which wouldn't normally appear :-D So this is how by being too diligent can turn out contraproductive :-)